# How to Pass Variables data from python application to apache webserver

Tags: python, apache, twisted

I'm trying to build a webserver using Apache and I want to establish two-way of communication between my python application and webserver where I can listen for requests from apache and return data back, in the same time I want the client to interact only with the webserver.

In my python program I'm using python python-twisted and pymodbus (MODBUS-TCPIP) to get some data from a PLC.

I have already configured a websocket in python using

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol, \
WebSocketServerFactory
```

I'm thinking to configure a intermediate web which will be initiated upon http request of the main website and open websocket connection with python and start receiving data, where the clients (browsers) can still request data using jquery.

I don't know if this is the right way to go. Do you guys have better way to pass data variable between python and apache back and forth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to make PLC data accessible on a web page.

The right way to develop a web application in Python is to use a web framework like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com), or (if you want something lighter) [bottle](https://bottlepy.org)

With this, you can develop a web page where you connect to your PLC over Modbus, query some values, disconnect and return a response with data as json.

But I think, this is not the best architecture because if you have several people accessing your web page, it will cause several connections to your PLC and you may have poor performance for your web app.

I think you had better develop a modbus program which is reading the data from the PLC and store it into a database. Then your web app just gets the data from the database.

I hope it helps